# The StackExchange Winter Bash is on again for 2013, Everyone Keen?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Each year SE sites can opt-in to participate in the [Winter Hat Bash](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com). I'm game for enabling on our site, does anyone have any objections? If not I'll fill in the form.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Rock on with that action!

Comment: Hats on!!!!!!!!

Comment: Who doesn't like hats?

Comment: Love hats in winters :)

Comment: Of course, it's summer here, but hey! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well 24 hours or so seemed like enough time for something as trivial as hats, so we're signed up! :)

Comment: When does it start?

Comment: 16th of December apparently! From the email we received: "This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event."